# Problems initializing a class in Swift

Tags: swift, class, generics

I'm trying to write a class for a binary tree. The tree class itself just has pointer to the root node, and then the nodes within the tree point to other nodes. I was each node to also have user-specified type data depending on the application of the tree, so I made the node class generic with type T. Since the node class is generic in T, it seemed to me I had to make the tree class generic in T as well so I could pass T to the one empty node I create when I create my tree.

Here's my test code:

```
enum NodeKind {
  case notAssigned
  case leaf
  case tree
}

class Node<T> {
  var kind  = NodeKind.notAssigned
  var parent: Node<T>?   // if a tree node, pointer to parent node, else nil
  var child0: Node<T>?   // if a tree node, points to a child if it exists, else nil
  var child1: Node<T>?   // optionals are automatically inited to nil
  var data:   T          // data type of the user data
  
  init( data: T) {
    self.data = data
  }
}

class BinaryTree<T> {
  var root: Node<T>  // pointer to the root of the binary tree
  
  init( data: T) {
    root = Node<T>( data: T)  // create one empty node at the root
  }
}

var testTree = BinaryTree<Int>( data: 5)
```

My intent is that the last statement should create a BinaryTree instance with nodes containing user data of type Int, and the root of var testTree should point to a single Node instance with data == 5 and no children nor parent.

However, the last line gets a compiler error:

`Cannot convert value of type 'T.Type' to expected argument type 'T'`

There were various suggested fixes, but none of them worked. How should I write this?

Secondly, what does "T.Type" mean? I'm not familiar with this construct.

Thanks, Eric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### First question:

In your `BinaryTree` class's initializer, I assume you are trying to create a new `Node<T>` that stores the input `data` of type `T`. However, you are assigning the type `T` to `data`, instead the actual `data` itself.

To fix this, change your `BinaryTree` class's initializer:

```swift
init(data: T) {
    root = Node<T>(data: data)  // create one empty node at the root
}
```

---

#### Second question

`T.Type` means the **type** of the thing itself (in this case `Int`), but not an instance of this thing (in this case `5`).

Comment: Yes, thanks, that fixed it. I feel I should have caught that but couldn't see it. Thanks for answering both questions.